# Implementing RadPanelBar

Tags: asp.net, telerik

HI,

I have a table with 3 columns Itemid(int),Itemname(string),ItemDesc(string).. Im trying to use a radpanelbar to display this information, where the bar initially shows the item name and on clik/expansion it will show the item description.. I tried looking at the examples on telerik site but didnt understand the point of **datafieldid** and **datafieldparentid**. What are they used for and what would their values be for my table.. I tried using different combination of column names for these two ids but I still didnt get it..

Can someone point me in the right direction..

Thanks,
J. Adams

Answer (score 0):

These properties are used when you bind the panelbar to self-referencing hierarchical table with id->parentid columns related in primary->foreign key style. Your table structure does not seem to be hierarchical and you can populate the control only with root items or build its items with your own logic.